# Excel : How to set criteria for searching value in one column from another in excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column that contains strings with values that i want to search.

Example:

Column A (my raw data): SMS APP, SMS Solutions

Column B (my search criterias):SMS

Column C: =vlookup(Column B, Column C, FALSE)

As shown above, I would like to ensure that Column C will display the results of my search on my raw data. Is there a vlookup way to do it?. It must match a string shown in Column B. thanks!

Comment: What do you indend to do? You cannot use `VLOOKUP` (or a formula) on the very same column of the data (Column C in your example is *within* your `VLOOKUP` and contains your formula. This **won't work**

Comment: I think you have mistyped this line Column C: =vlookup(Column B, Column C, FALSE) Did you mean Column C: =vlookup(Column B, Column A, FALSE)? Actual syntax should be like '=VLOOKUP(B1,A:A,1)'

Comment: What do you mean by "the results"? You mean the cell it was found? How many times it was found? If it was found?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a full blown UDF that will give you back a list of all the cells that contained the word in B then (note this works with multi-column ranges as well):

```
=ListAll(B1, A1:A100)
```

(code)

```vb
Function ListAll(ByVal text As String, _
                 ByVal cell_range As Range, _
                 Optional seperator As String = ", ") As String

Dim result As String
Dim i As Long, j as Long
Dim rawData As Variant
rawData = cell_range.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(rawData, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(rawData, 2)
        If InStr(1, rawData(i, j), text) <> 0 Then
            result = result & (rawData(i, j) & seperator)
        End If
    Next
Next

If Len(result) <> 0 Then
    result = Left$(result, Len(result) - Len(seperator))
End If

ListAll = result

End Function
```

Notice I set it up so that each value found is seperated by a comma, but you can do other stuff like line breaks:

```
=ListAll(B1, A1:A100, CHAR(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with the =SEARCH(find_text, within_text) formula, which returns an integer if find_text is found within_text, and returns #VALUE! if the text is not found. So, just make column D which searches values in column A for values in Column B.  If column D is integer, that means match.  If column D is #VALUE - no match.